# Delete duplicate rows from large (> 100 MIo) postgresql table (truncate with condition?)

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418122/delete-duplicates-from-large-dataset-100mio-rows), I have a large table which stores all events in our systems, for one event type I have duplicate rows (mistakenly exported from another system several times). I need to delete them to clear out stats. The solution proposed above was to

- insert the records -- without duplicates -- into a temporary table,
- truncate the original table and insert them back in.

But in my situation I need to delete only one class of events, not all rows,  which is [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704834/truncate-with-condition) with `truncate`. I'm wondering whether or not I can benefit from postgres USING syntax like in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4442825/1317325) , which offers the following solution -

```
DELETE FROM user_accounts 
USING user_accounts ua2   
WHERE user_accounts.email = ua2.email AND user_account.id < ua2.id;
```

The problem is that I don't have id field in this large table. So what will be the fastest decision in this situation? 
DELETE + INSERT from temporary table is the only option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* use the `ctid` column as a "replacement id":

```
DELETE FROM user_accounts 
USING user_accounts ua2   
WHERE user_accounts.email = ua2.email 
  AND user_account.ctid < ua2.ctid;
```

Although that raises another question: why doesn't your `user_accounts` table have a primary key?

But if you delete a substantial part of the rows in the table then `delete` will never be very efficient (and the comparison on `ctid` isn't a quick one either because it does not have an index). So the `delete` will most probably take a very long time.

For a one time operation and if you need to delete many rows, then inserting those you want to keep into an intermediate table is going to be *much* faster.

That method can be improved by simply keeping the intermediate table instead of copying the rows back to the original table.

```
-- this will create the same table including indexes and not null constraint
-- but NOT foreign key constraints!
create table temp (like user_accounts including all);

insert into temp 
select distinct ... -- this is your query that removes the duplicates
from user_accounts;

 -- you might need cascade if the table is referenced by others
drop table user_accounts;

alter table temp rename to user_accounts;

commit;
```

The only drawback is that you have to re-create foreign keys for the original table (fks referencing the original table and foreign keys from the original table to a different one).

Comment: the example I used was not my table but code used in SO answer. Don't have id field, so will use your solution with intermediate table.
But I can't actually drop table, so I need to delete duplicate rows from it, which is very slow.. Hoped for some miracle solution :)

Comment: @RInatM: why can't you drop the table? Is it constantly being accessed? Are you aware that the create/drop/insert/rename can be done in a single *transaction* in Postgres so other session won't see the change until it is committed?

Comment: Maybe worth the link which describes, *every* table has a `ctid` column. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-system-columns.html

Comment: @pozs thanks, I didn't know about that. 
Yes, it's contantly being accessed and lots of views depend on it. And it's huge - I need to delete about 5M rows for one type of events, but together with others this table consists more than 100M rows.